# BeautifulSoup returning none when I can see that the element exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the link to the image on this reddit website for practice, but BS4 seems to be returning none whenever I use find() to find the class of the object. Any help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

page = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/qswblq/the_frontier_by_me_5120x2880/")
soup = soup(page.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.find(class_="ImageBox-image")['src'])
```

Comment: modern pages use JavaScript to add elements in HTML but `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`

Comment: when I run your code then I get URL. First you should check what you get in `page.content` - maybe you get HTML with warning for bots/scripts/hackers/spamers and maybe it try to display `ReCaptcha` to check if you are human.

Comment: Agree with @furas, you might have to use Selenium

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there is an alternativ, you can use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Instead of `requests` it will render the site like a browser and will give `page_source` you could inspect and find your element.

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDIVER')
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/qswblq/the_frontier_by_me_5120x2880/')
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')

soup.find(class_="ImageBox-image")['src']
```